# Certificate fingerprints don't match after export

Tags: android, eclipse, certificate, keystore, fingerprint

Hello I have a problem,

When I try to upload my app to the Google Play Developer Console, it says the certificate fingerprints missmatch and shows another fingerprint than I'm seeing when I export the APK via Eclipse(in the last pane of the export wizard under SHA1 Fingerprint). The fingerprint I'm seeing in eclipse is the correct one, I know this because I used it to generate a GoogleMaps API key and It's the same as it should be according to the missmatch error.

So basically what I think is happening is that Eclipse is signing my apk with another certificate than I'm telling it to use. Tough when I sign it using the debug keystore the fingerprints match(the one i'm seeing in eclipse vs the one that's displayed in the missmatch error) wich is very weird.

This problem occured after I replaced my harddrives. But I'm sure I am using the correct keystore because I backed it up before and am using the same one. Plus the fingerprint it's showing in Eclipse matches the one it should be according to the error.

Could it have something to do with the 'google-play-services-lib' project that's used as a library? Or because I'm using another debug keystore(after reïnstalling windows)?

Comment: Make sure you enter the correct key password as it will give wrong fingerprint if you enter it wrong (it will not fail)

Comment: I'm sure it is correct, because when I change the password it says 'Could not recover key' in the last pane of the Export wizard. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: You can try to use the same SHA version you used in the first application

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean,

Both the eclipse fingerprint and the one on the website are SHA1 fingerprints. The one it should be and is according to eclipse is something like 
SHA1: 71:A4:3E:90:2E:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:4F:CC:8A:26:9F:96:C7:D7

And the one in the developer console is something like: [ SHA1: 47:0F:EF:85:56:ED:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:39:BB ]

Comment: I mean try to use the same JDK (1.6 for e.g.)

Comment: Hi, figured it out. Thanks for the tips though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with the apksigner of the ADT package I downloaded(the official version from the website I might add). 
I exported an unsigned apk, used the 'apk-signer' utility(http://www.haibison.com/apps/apk-signer) to sign it, and sure enough it worked.

Not sure what is causing this issue.. I guess it's some kind of compatibility issue with my certificate because the fingerprint of the debug keystore did not change. And that one is generated by the ADT package.